# Return numeric Zero from a javascript function

Tags: javascript

There is a `function` that returns `key` of an `object` based on some condition, if the `key` it is returning is `0`, then the value I get is `undefined`

```
var obj = {'some','values'};

function getObjectKey(){

   obj.forEach(function(value, key) {
      if(some condition){
         return key;
       }
    });

}

var objectKey = getObjectKey();
console.log(objectKey); //returns `undefined` if the key returned is 0.
```

How can I get the key if the key is 0?

Comment: please change the obj to a valid object. as it is written, it could be an array as well with wrong brackets.

Comment: [JavaScript objects use strings for keys](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/188/objects#t=201610151230320519827&a=remarks)

Comment: @downvoter: May I knw whats the reason for downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another methode, because [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does not have a short circuit for ending the loop.

In this case, use better [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
function getObjectKey(object, condition){
    var k;

    Object.keys(object).some(function(key) {
        if (condition(object[key])) {
            k = key;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return k;
}

var object = { zero: 0, one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4, five: 5 };

console.log(getObjectKey(object, function (v) { return v === 3; }));
```

With ES6, you could use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

> The **`find()`** method returns a **value** in the array, if an element in the array satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) is returned.

```js
function getObjectKey(object, condition) {
    return Object.keys(object).find(function(key) {
        return condition(object[key]);
    });
}

var object = { zero: 0, one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4, five: 5 };

console.log(getObjectKey(object, v => v === 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify keys in the object.

This is not valid syntax:

```
{'some','values'};
```

This would be an array:

```
[ 'some','values' ];
```

But you really want an object, so put in the keys:

```
 { "key0": "some", "key1": "values" };
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// there was a syntax error with your obj
var obj = {
  'some': 'values', 
  'another': 'anotherValue',
  'zero': 0,
  'null': null
}

// you should take the object and the key with the function
function getObjectKey(obj, key){
  var keys = Object.keys(obj)
  var index = keys.indexOf(key)
  // if the bitshifted index is truthy return the key else return undefined
  return ~index
    ? obj[keys[index]]
    : void 0 // void value - will change the value given to it to undefined
}


console.log(getObjectKey(obj, 'some'))
console.log(getObjectKey(obj, 'another'))
console.log(getObjectKey(obj, 'doesntExist'))
console.log(getObjectKey(obj, 'zero'))
console.log(getObjectKey(obj, 'null'))
```